zephyr run multile threads in test
I have an application in zephyr that starts multiple tasks that interact with each other. The Task in question read ans set a meter and valve. Virtual representations of these are present.
I now want to add some tests to this project. One of them is verifying that the task is running and reacting correctly.
I managed to get the thread of the task running in twister, but not parallel to my own test thread.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.1)
set(APP_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../..)

list(APPEND ZEPHYR_EXTRA_MODULES ${APP_ROOT}/src/drivers/meter)
list(APPEND ZEPHYR_EXTRA_MODULES ${APP_ROOT}/src/drivers/valve)

list(APPEND SYSCALL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${APP_ROOT}/include/)

find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
project(MyProject)
zephyr_include_directories(${ZEPHYR_BASE}/include/zephyr/drivers/)

# C sources
target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)
target_sources(app PRIVATE ${APP_ROOT}/src/task/MterTask.c)

The task thread is started in the task source file with:
K_THREAD_DEFINE(metertask_id, METER_TASK_STACKSIZE, _meter_thread, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        METER_TASK_PRIORITY, K_ESSENTIAL, 0);

As the threads are not tunning parallel I manually have to stop the test thread with k_sleep().
This however doesn't work with my helper functions that give me information from the task.
Like remaining Liters or the value of the virtual meter.
Is there a way to make twister run the threads in parallel?

I was looking at the wrong problem here.
Instead of giving the address of a variable, in my test, to write the value. I actually gave a pointer to address 0. That's why the task got stuck and the test terminated after its timeout.
So a classic pointer fail. But zephyr/twister also missed mentioning my mistake.
I do still have to use k_sleep in a few places to ensure the scheduler give the task enough time. Refactor of the task could remove this, though.
